# Import - database not found error

Tags: mysql

When I issue the following command:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword database_name < /path_to_database.sql
```

I get:

> sh: database_name: not found

And it stops processing. I have created `database_name` and it exists.

Can somebody help? I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: works here perfectly. are you sure you dont have a database_name typo ?

Comment: Yes, very sure it's not a typo

Comment: The same format used to work earlier with my shared host. But now I'm testing linode with ubuntu 10.04 and it's giving me error.

Comment: so something changed, u are on a new box and might have permission issues. that is important info left out if it is

Comment: I have granted the user all privileges. Have tried using root too. So I'm pretty sure it's not permission related issue.

Comment: You are running the command from *rsh*, *ssh* or similar don't you? The error is coming from **sh**, not *mysql*

Comment: @ring0 is onto something. Vishal, can you provide any more detail about the exact command being run, as well as perhaps some info on the current shell with `echo $0` or `ps -p $$`? The syntax from your command should work perfectly in Lucid, but it might be playing up if you're using an uncommon shell, running it inside a script, or trying to issue the command remotely.